# CSS Grid layout with gutters

Tags: html, css

I need a layout like so:

[image]

Here is my try:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    [full-start] minmax(0, 1fr)
    [main-start] minmax(0, 55.625em) [main-end]
    minmax(0, 1fr) [full-end];
}

.grid-container > * {
  grid-column: full-start / full-end;
}

.header {
  background: #0e9daf;
}

.main {
  background: #9E9E9E;
  grid-column: main-start;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #dd9f32;
}

.footer {
  background: #9b51e0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="gridlayout.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>

    <main class="main">
      Main
    </main>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <footer class="footer">
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the screen is wider, let's say a 1080p screen, the main content has gutters on the left and right side, but the header and footer extends the full page.

Think about something like this, but I'm achieving it with grid:

```
  .main {
     max-width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

On larger displays, I would like to split the main area in two portions, I need a content area (a list of all blog posts) and a sidebar on the right with widgets such as "recent posts", "search bar", etc). I need some gap (not much) between the content and sidebar.

On small screens, I would like the header first, the blog posts below the header, the widgets below the blog posts, and the footer last.

I'm not even sure if I approached this the right way. I would love to hear your opinions. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is there something not working like you'd wish?

Answer (score 3):

You can use template-areas (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) to achieve this quite easy. If you want the layout to change with different resolutions, just add @media queries and define a new grid-template-area.

(I changed minmax(0, 55.625em) to minmax(0, 400px) for visual effect below)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns:  1fr minmax(0, 300px) minmax(0, 100px) 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header header header header"
     ". main sidebar ."
     "footer footer footer footer"
  ;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #0e9daf;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #9E9E9E;
  grid-column: main-start;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: #dd9f32;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #9b51e0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>

    <main class="main">
      Main
    </main>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <footer class="footer">
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know about template areas. I used them in a holy grail layout, but in that layout I had everything stretched out, header, sidebars,content, and footer. What I try to achieve I think is what Rachel Andrew's wrote here https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/06/01/breaking-out-with-css-grid-explained/
however I need to additionaly split the center content in two parts, a main area and a sidebar. In your example the main and sidebar are on top of each other.

Comment: Updated the answer - not 100% sure what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. Your code works great. I just need some gap between the main and the sidebar, but I think that can be added with "grid-gap: 10px" Am I right? On the mobile I will add a media query to move those block on top of each other.

Comment: Yes, grid-column-gap (added to answer)

Comment: @Tibbelit why has `grid-colum: main-start` been added? It seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

using `grid-template-areas`, you can easily achieve the desired layout

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 15%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 2%;
  grid-template-areas: "h h h h" "m m m s" "f f f f";
}

.header {
  background: #0e9daf;
  grid-area: h;
}

.main {
  background: #9E9E9E;
  grid-area: m;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #dd9f32;
  grid-area: s;
}

.footer {
  background: #9b51e0;
  grid-area: f;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-areas: "h h h h" "m m m m" "s s s s" "f f f f";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1080px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 10% 62% 12% 10%;
    grid-template-areas: "h h h h" ". m s ." "f f f f";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <header class="header">
    Header
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    Main
  </main>

  <aside class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </aside>

  <footer class="footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I'm looking for, except I need the header and footer to stretch out completely

Answer (score 0):

You can split the middle column and have 4 columns instead of 3 and you consider media query to switch back to 3 columns:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 40.625em) minmax(0, 15em) minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.grid-container>* {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.header {
  background: #0e9daf;
}

.main {
  background: #9E9E9E;
  grid-column: 2;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #dd9f32;
  grid-column: 3;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.footer {
  background: #9b51e0;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 55.625em) minmax(0, 1fr);
  }
  .main,
  .sidebar {
    grid-column: 2;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <header class="header">
    Header
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    Main
  </main>

  <aside class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </aside>

  <footer class="footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```